# autocomplete for textboxs in a repeater control

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net

How to apply autocomplete for a repeater control? I am adding 4 text boxes in one button click which is binded to repeater.

I want to apply autocomplete to one of the textbox in every add click. I also have my webmethod to fetch data by json.

```
    protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Employee> dtEmployee = new List<Employee>();
        dtEmployee = GetEmployee();
        if (Session["EmployeeTable"] != null)
        {
            dtEmployee = (List<Employee>)Session["EmployeeTable"];

            rptEmployee.DataSource = dtEmployee;
            rptEmployee.DataBind();
            rptEmployee.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            rptEmployee.DataSource = null;
            rptEmployee.DataBind();
            rptEmployee.Visible = false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: you better check this link https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Answer (score 0):

Please check the code hope this helps:

```
<input type=textbox" name="txt1" class="autocomplete"/>
<input type=textbox" name="txt2" class="autocomplete"/>
$(".autocomplete").autocomplete("samefile.php");
```

Also if check this link for getting data using json if you require:

https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp